# Function slicing dataframe using index

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has a column called Country and I am changing it into the index in my function. Here is what I am doing:

```
def checking(*args):
    check=pd.read_excel('mydata.xlsx', index_col=0)
    data=check.loc[[args]]
    return data
```

Unfortunately when I do the following to select only the rows that have Japan:

```
japan=ckecking('Japan')
```

I have the error below:

```
 None of [Index([('Japan'),], dtype='object', name='Country')] are in the [index]
```

But I am able to convert that Country into the index and select the rows containing Japan without this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly modify your function

```
def checking(*args):
    check=pd.read_excel('mydata.xlsx', index_col=0)
    data=check.loc[args]
    return data
```